# Cannot compile app with Carthage dependencies after Xcode update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage, trustkit

After Xcode auto update to version 13.2.1, I can't build project with Carthage dependencies manager.
With one framework got from here: https://gitlab.com/trustpayments-public/mobile-sdk/ios
I get the error following:
`Module compiled with Swift 5.5 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler`

I tried rebuilding framework and set `Build libraries for distribution` flag in project settings to `No` but it returned the error that bridging headers are not allowed.

Any ideas ?

P.S. I managed to build the app with CocoaPods, but environmental requirements force me to remain with Carthage in my iOS project.

Comment: What's the `carthage` command you use to build the external frameworks?

Comment: `Carthage update --platform ios --use-xcframeworks`

Answer (score 6):

OK, I managed to compile my project.
Steps to do:

1. Remove `../Carthage/Build folder`
2. Run `xcodebuild -version` and check is it the newest one.
3. Run `carthage build --platform ios --use-xcframeworks --no-use-binaries`